# What does `forall` mean in this specific signature? (definition of Task in a build system in Haskell)

Tags: haskell, forall

I am reading the paper [Build systems à la carte](https://simon.peytonjones.org/assets/pdfs/build-systems-jfp.pdf) by A. Mokhov, N. Mitchell and S. Peyton Jones.

One of the first concepts they define is that of a `Task`. It has type

```haskell
newtype Task c k v = Task ( forall f. c f => (k -> f v) -> f v )
```

where `c`is a constraint (e.g. `Applicative` or `Monad`), `k` is the type of keys, and `v` of values.

I need some help parsing the meaning `forall f` in the above definition. If the definition of `Task` had been

```haskell
newtype Task k v = Task ( (k -> v) -> v )
```

then it would be clear: a Task is a way to build a value in `v`, given a way `(k -> v)` to retrieve its inputs from the corresponding keys.

If we add `f` to the mix, what changes? How can one even define a task, if it must accept inputs of type `(k -> f v)` for any possible `f` satisfying `c`?

Comment: In Haskell it is possible to work with _polymorphic functions_, i.e. functions working on multiple types: these have a type of the form `forall a ...`. These can also be passed to functions ("higher rank functions" are those accepting polymorphic functions), as well as stored inside `data`/`newtype`s. For instance, `foo :: (forall a. a -> Int -> a) -> (String, Bool)` could be defined as `foo f = (f "hello" 21, f True 42)` -- note how `f` is used on multiple types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have correctly understood the forall - the function must work for any possible f.

To define a task remember we will know what c is, so we can use the facilities of Applicative or Monad.

Let's say we want a `Task Monad Int String`

```
t :: Task Monad Int String
t = Task taskFunction
```

So we need a function that will work for any monad.

```
taskFunction :: forall f . Monad f => (Int -> f String) -> f String
```

(The forall could be left out in this signature, it would be implied anyway.)

And we write it using bind, return, do notation, etc.

```
taskFunction getter = do x <- getter 37
                         y <- getter 42
                         return (x ++ y)
```